# How to show the preview of epub file (ipad and kindlefire) in a web page?

Tags: php, html, css, epub

In my project, users can write books online and save it as a  `epub` file. I need to implement a functionality which enables the user to see the preview of epub file. There will be two tabs  in preview page. One is for `kindlefire` and other is for `ipad`. I have saved all the datas (`XHTML, css, content, etc`) of epub file in the database. The preview should give the exact look of the book in `kindlefire` and `ipad`. Is it ok to use normal html and css to generate preview of book ? If there is any other straight forward method for this, please suggest me

Answer (score 2):

I think that you shouldn't aim for the EXACT look on those devices, instead just view the html and css (of course, test it on those devices anyway). People usually don't mind if there are small differences like gaps or paddings somewhere, the main thing is text anyway. Unless, of course, you have difficult tables and media content.

Comment: I totally agree. This is the same story as with different web browsers. If you're a designer, you need to check on every browser to see how you site looks like. The target devices use different rendering engines and this makes it impractical for you to promise 100% real preview. However, showing a fast preview based on the metrics of the target device may be beneficial for the end users.